# Style color not applied to WebGLPointsLayer layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers, webgl

I'm using a WebGLPointsLayer layer from OpenLayers(7.3.0) and I'm having a problem changing the style color based on a value.

In the following example, the color value is declared as a global variable. This is fine,
[Filtering features with WebGL](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/filter-points-webgl.html)

but...

If you want to dynamically change the color based on the value as shown in the source code below, it will not work properly. style.variables.oc and style.variables.nc are data-dependent values and are written in [expression format](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_expressions.html).

```
const style = {
  variables: {
    minYear: 1850,
    maxYear: 2015,
    oc: 'rgba(242,56,22,0.61)',
    nc: '#ffe52c',
  },
  filter: ['between', ['get', 'year'], ['var', 'minYear'], ['var', 'maxYear']],
  symbol: {
    symbolType: 'circle',
    size: [
      '*',
      ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['get', 'mass'], 0, 8, 200000, 26],
      ['-', 1.75, ['*', animRatio, 0.75]],
    ],
    color: ['interpolate', ['linear'], animRatio, 0, ['var', 'oc'], 1, ['var', 'nc']],
    opacity: ['-', 1.0, ['*', animRatio, 0.75]],
  },
};


cosnt layer = new WebGLPointsLayer({
  style: style,
  source: vectorSource,
  disableHitDetection: true,
});
```

My guess is that it's the special characters that are causing the problem.

Comment: It seems it does not like having whole color expressions as variables, but it does work if you make the rgba components variables https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-points-webgl-forked-pttu9u?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I don't think the # or parenthesis character () should be there, is it a bug? It didn't matter when it was a global variable.

Comment: I do not think it is a bug.  A color string would be parsed into an array when the style is created, and only simple values which do not need parsing can be used as variables.